# Security concerns for making $db['default']['_protect_identifiers']= FALSE;

Tags: codeigniter, security

When I upgraded to new CI version, it is adding backticks to every group by and other queries. So I would like to disable it using `$db['default']['_protect_identifiers']= FALSE;` in database.php cofig file. This has any impact on security  ?

Comment: Which version are you using ? I didnt find `$db['default']['_protect_identifiers']` in DB config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backticks keep your table and field names from conflicting with the DB keywords. They have nothing to do with security